# Snippet to allow just 1 active Subscription at WooCommerce Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I've got a snippet which allows to have just one active subscription, so they can't order another until canceled.

But this snippet also blocks the up-downgrade-function. Any Ideas how I can get just the switch subscription part aviable?

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_num_of_subscriptions', 10, 2);
function check_num_of_subscriptions( $valid, $product_id )
{
    $product_to_add = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    if ( $product_to_add instanceof WC_Product_Subscription || $product_to_add instanceof WC_Product_Variable_Subscription) {

        // alternative use: $has_sub = wcs_user_has_subscription( '', '', 'active' );
        if ( has_active_subscription() ) {
            // cart validation must fail, because user is not allowed to have multiple subscriptions

            wc_clear_notices();
            wc_add_notice(__('Du hast bereits ein aktives Abonnement.', 'woocommerce'), 'error');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}

function has_active_subscription()
{

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $active_subscriptions = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value' => $user_id,
        'post_type' => 'shop_subscription',
        'post_status' => 'wc-active'

    ));
    if (!empty($active_subscriptions))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `up-downgrade-function`?

Comment: We've got 3 packages (subscriptions) they normaly can switch between them. But of course they are routed to the checkout page by switching. But this is blocked by the script, because the user already have a active subscription. (the script should just block the function that the user is not allowed to book 2 subscriptions on the same time.

Comment: Why not just at add to cart to clear cart and add the product ? On the product use the checkbox sold individualy to avoid quantity problems.

Comment: Here is a snipet for one item in cart - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-allow-1-product-cart/

Comment: Guys, I don't want to check to go with 1 item to checkout, it should check for logged in users if they have a active subscription and dont let them order another one. But for the Up-Downgrading functionallity he also takes a new package to the checkout.

Comment: Then compare product subscription level and user subscription level if match he is ordering the same if not its up or downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_num_of_subscriptions', 10, 2);
    
    function check_num_of_subscriptions( $valid, $product_id ){
        $product_to_add = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        if ($product_to_add instanceof WC_Product_Subscription || $product_to_add instanceof WC_Product_Variable_Subscription){
                    // alternative use: $has_sub = wcs_user_has_subscription( '', '', 'active' );
                    
                    if ( has_active_subscription() && (! has_woocommerce_subscription('',$product_id,''))) {
                        // cart validation must fail, because user is not allowed to have multiple subscriptions
                        wc_clear_notices();
                        wc_add_notice(__('You already have an active subscription.', 'woocommerce'), 'error');
                        return false;
                    } else{
                        return true;
                    }
         }
        return $valid;
    }
    function has_active_subscription(){
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $active_subscriptions = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value' => $user_id,
            'post_type' => 'shop_subscription',
            'post_status' => 'wc-active'
    
        ));
        if (!empty($active_subscriptions))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    function has_woocommerce_subscription($the_user_id, $the_product_id, $the_status) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if (empty($the_user_id)) {
            $the_user_id = $current_user->ID;
        }
        if (WC_Subscriptions_Manager::user_has_subscription( $the_user_id, $the_product_id, $the_status)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

this  Code will run for upgrade and downgrade, tested and working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).